# Concatenating Mp3 files into one : Chrome issue

Tags: c#, google-chrome, mp3, concatenation

Hi I use NAudio and this piece of code to concatenate multiple mp3 files together.

```
            Mp3FileReader reader = new Mp3FileReader(file);

            if ((output.Position == 0) && (reader.Id3v2Tag != null))
            {
                output.Write(reader.Id3v2Tag.RawData, 0, reader.Id3v2Tag.RawData.Length);
            }
            Mp3Frame frame;

            while ((frame = reader.ReadNextFrame()) != null)
            {
                output.Write(frame.RawData, 0, frame.RawData.Length);
            }
```

The problem is that when I read the output file in Google Chrome (no problem with IE or Firefox),
Chrome seems to determine the total duration of the file with the first mp3 file that has been concatenated. Like if I have 3 files

- 1.mp3 (6 seconds long)
- 2.mp3 (8 seconds long)
- 3.mp3  (4 seconds long)
- output.mp3 (18 seconds long)

Chrome will pretend that the duration of the new file is only 6 seconds whilst it should be 18 seconds.

There might be a frame that indicates the end of file ? Is it possible? If yes which frame should I avoid writing to the output file ? 
Is there a common frame header to specify the real file duration ?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the files have different bitrate so in effect you're creating a variable bitrate file and it looks like Google Chrome doesn't handle them correctly. This is common a common issue with MP3 players that do not handle variable bitrates correctly.

Also this is only safe if you're concatenating whole files. If for example you want to concatenate the 2nd half of a file to another then you need to parse the frame sideinfo and look for the field main_data_begin, if it is zero then it's ok to append. If it is non-zero then the frame's audio data starts one or more frames behind so you need to look for the next frame with main_data_begin == 0.

Edit:
After thinking about it, you don't want to do that at all because:

1. MP3 files attenuate the 1st frame so encoders pad the input with zeroes at the beginning (that's why an MP3 file is slightly larger than the original file after decoding), so there will be a short silence at the concatenation point.
2. Every MP3 frame's first half is overlapped with the 2nd half of the last frame during decoding, so concating will also introduce glitches.